# Continuous functions satisfying $ f ( 1 - x ) = 1 - f \big( f ( x ) \big) $

Tags: continuity, contest-math, functional-equations

> **Problem.** Find all continuous functions $ f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R $ such that for all $ x \in \mathbb R $, we have
> $$ f ( 1 - x ) = 1 - f \big( f ( x ) \big) \text . $$

I have obtained that $ f ( x ) = f \bigg( f \Big( f \big( f ( x ) \big) \Big) \bigg) $ for all $ x \in \mathbb R $, but can't go any further. To see this, we substitute $ x = f \big( f ( x ) \big) $ to get
$$
f \Big( 1 - f \big( f ( y ) \big) \Big) = 1 - f \bigg( f \Big( f \big( f ( x ) \big) \Big) \bigg) \\
\implies f \big( f ( 1 - y ) \big) = 1 - f \bigg( f \Big( f \big( f ( x ) \big) \Big) \bigg) \\
\implies 1 - f ( y ) = 1 - f \bigg( f \Big( f \big( f ( x ) \big) \Big) \bigg) \\
\implies f(y) = 1 - f \bigg( f \Big( f \big( f ( x ) \big) \Big) \bigg) \text .
$$
I am guessing the only solutions are $ f ( x ) = x $ and $ f ( x ) = \frac 1 2 $. Does anyone have a proof?

**Edit:** I can prove that if $ f $ is continuous and $ f \Big( f \big( f ( x ) \big) \Big) = x $ for all $ x \in \mathbb R $, then $ f ( x ) = x $ is the only solution. But the condition here is slightly weaker than that, and that's why $ f ( x ) = \frac 1 2 $ also works. But is it possible to adapt the proof?

Comment: Maybe that a graphical approach give to us some clue about a formal proof.

Comment: You have solved it yourself. Which function can for every value be endless concatenated without any change of the result ?

Comment: @user90369 But the function can change, it's just that starting at $f(x)$ every 3 iterations it must go back to itself.

Comment: I think, this does not much matter, you have at least $f(f(f(x)))=x$. If $f(x)\ne x$ then I think the difference cannot be reduced to $0$ by concatenating $f(x)$ a finite number of times - and this is left, which has to be proofed.

Comment: If you read this, you can understand. http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~lototsky/PiMuEp/FunctionalEquations.pdf

Answer (score 1):

First note: There are other (continuous but non-polynomial) solutions. For example $$f(x) = \begin{cases} 0 & \text{if $x < 0$} \\ x & \text{if $0 \leq x \leq 1$} \\ 1 & \text{if $x > 1$}  \end{cases}$$

More generally: The class of functions that are equal to the identity on the interval $[\frac{1}{2}-a,\frac{1}{2}+a]$ for $0 \leq a \leq \infty$ and constant* (with respective value $\frac{1}{2}-a$ or $\frac{1}{2}+a$) outside that interval. So the two you found are the extreme cases of this class, and its only polynomial ones.

I'm fairly confident these are all solutions*. I'd try something along these lines: Let $R$ be the range of $f$. From your identity $ffff = f$ follows that $fff(x) = x$ for all $x \in R$. Now let $\bar f$ be the restriction of $f$ to $R$. Given that $\bar f \bar f \bar f = id$ on $R$, you can show that $\bar f$ is bijective. Also, by continuity and the intermediate value theorem, $R$ must be connected (i.e. if $a<b<c$ and $a,c \in R$ then $b \in R$). This can be used to show that $\bar f$ is the identity on $R$ (e.g. using that every continuous bijection on an interval is monotonic). Now use the original functional equation to show that if $M = \sup(R)$ then $m = \inf(R) = 1 - M$, that $M,m \in R$ and that for all $x>M$ we have $f(x)=f(M)=M$* (the latter can be proved by contradiction). Similarly, if $x<m$, then $f(x)=f(m)=m$*.

*Corrected after comment: for all $x$ outside $R$, it's necessary and sufficient that

i) $f(x) \in R$

ii) $f$ is continuous

iii) the graph has rotational symmetry of order 2 at the centre $(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2})$

Comment: f(x)=0, 1 does not work.

Comment: Your proof is correct. But although my computation is same.

Comment: I've changed the notation to make it clearer. How does my example not work?

Comment: Your discussion conclude f(x)=x. It must be m equal M. And differentiable. But f(x)=0 lead, 0 equal 1.

Comment: Nice observations, but the last one ($ f ( x ) = M $ for $ x > M $ and $ f ( x ) = m $ for $ x < m $) is in fact wrong. Let for example $ R = [ 0 , 1 ] $ and $ f ( x ) = \cases { \sin ^ 2 \left( \frac \pi 2 x \right) & $ x < 0 \text { or } x > 1 $ \\ x & $ 0 \le x \le 1 $ } $.

Comment: You can change your argument a bit and show that every solution is of the form $ f ( x ) = \cases { x & $ \frac 1 2 - a \le x \le \frac 1 2 + a $ \\ g ( x ) & $ x \ge \frac 1 2 + a $ \\ 1 - g ( 1 - x ) & $ x \le \frac 1 2 - a $ } $ where $ a $ is a non-negative real number and $ g $ is a continuous real-valued function with domain $ \dom g = [ \frac 1 2 + a , + \infty ) $ such that $ g ( \frac 1 2 + a ) = \frac 1 2 + a $ and the range of $ g $ satisfies the condition $ \ran g \subseteq [ \frac 1 2 - a , \frac 1 2 + a ] $. It's easy to check that these are in fact solutions.